# Program is opening for a quarter of a second and then closing instantly

Tags: mac

After having this problem for over a month and not succeeding, I am asking you for help.

Sometimes (it is happening irregularly) a program is opening in the dock but closing again after a quarter of a second. I am not able to find out which program it is as it is happening so quickly.

Now my question: Is there any way to find out which apps (or processes) have been opened in the past minute (so that I can find out which program is responsible for this strange behavior).

I would be so glad if you could answer my question!

With best greetings,
Leon

Comment: Is this app opening on the left side of the dock? (to the left of Finder)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No it is not (it is opening left to the line that is dividing the downloads from the programs)

Comment: ok go to the apple menu - recent items and there will be a list of the last 10 apps you've opened. Also, please download and run malwarebytes to see if anything is off.

Comment: Check System Preferences > User & Groups > Login Items tab. Are there any apps listed there?

Comment: Use QuickTime to make a screen recording so you can see the Dock icon.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. The program is not listed in the last 10 apps. Yes only Google Chrome is listed there. I will try QuickTime to make a screen recording

Comment: Malwarebytes hat nichts gefunden...

Comment: Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Console app and leave it running. With the verbosity of recent versions of macOS, I'd be very surprised if the application doesn't leave log entries. Or at the very least the operating system doesn't leave log entries about it.

You could also leave a Terminal window open with the command `sudo fs_usage | grep open` running. This command will give you a list of every single file that is opened on your Mac. Which will be a surprising amount, but if you stop it (hold down CTRL and hit C) and check it immediately after seeing the application appear and disappear you should see what it is and where it is being loaded from.

Comment: I am trying it out now.

Comment: Thank you so much - it was an updating service of Dropbox, I have just changed the frequency of checking for an update!

Answer (score 1):

I notice mine doing that a lot and Force Quit did not work. What worked for me was to "right" click on the Finder icon and select "Show all windows". It will display all the windows it knows as being open. The smaller window icons are ones that it can no longer actually open but has a record of being open. Click on the small ones. Nothing will happen, but it will break the instance of that windows. Then select "Show all windows" again and you will see the last windows you selected is no longer listed. Repeat this for all of the smaller window icons until you're left with only large ones. You should be good to go.